# I cant get Crystal Reports if/then/else formula to pull correct data

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I built a great report with only one outstanding issue.  I am having trouble with my If/Then/Else statement in a formula field.  This is in Crystal XI.  I am by no means a seasoned developer, rather a self taught amatuer.

I have tried converting all nulls to default value, handling null values first, and just can't seem to get it right.

```
if isnull({@Place EXP Total}) 
then ({@Place EXP Total 2}) ELSE IF
not isnull({@Place EXP Total}) then 0
ELSE 0
```

if {@Place EXP Total} is null I expect to see {@Place EXP Total 2} but if there is something in {@Place EXP Total} I expect to see 0

Comment: Hi, In the formula editor you have a combobox with 2 values: Exception for Nulls and Default values for nulls. It should be set to Default values for nulls.

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting 0 only and it is set to Default value for nulls.

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts?